# Anyone know why the sprites aren't rendering in my pygames program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Currently, the code isn't giving any errors when I run it. Even if I just try to render a pipe at 0,0 with blit nothing pops up.

I already got the floor and bird to render properly, and everything else works fine. Only the pipes will not render.

I was following an online video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZg49z76cLw&t=14s, and even tried copying the code exactly, it just refuses to work for some reason.

```
import pygame
import sys

#defining screen size and clock variable
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((576,1024))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#bird physics
gravity = 0.25
bird_movement = 0



#importing all of the images, and doubling their size
bg_surface = pygame.image.load("Py games/assets/background-day.png").convert()
bg_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bg_surface)

floor_surface = pygame.image.load("Py games/assets/base.png").convert()
floor_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(floor_surface)


pipe_surface = pygame.image.load("Py games/assets/pipe-green.png").convert()
pipe_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(pipe_surface)
#making all clones of pipes have rectangles
pipe_list = []
#How often pipes are made
SPAWNPIPE = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(SPAWNPIPE,1200)


bird_surface = pygame.image.load("Py games/assets/bluebird-midflap.png").convert()
bird_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bird_surface)
#creating the rectangle around the bird
bird_rect = bird_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))



#Used to animate floor
floor_x_pos = 0 

def draw_floor():
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos,900))
    screen.blit(floor_surface,(floor_x_pos + 576,900))


#cloning of pipe
def create_pipe():
    new_pipe = pipe_surface.get_rect(midtop = (288,512))
    return new_pipe

def move_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        pipe.centerx -= 5
    return pipes

def draw_pipes(pipes):
    for pipe in pipes:
        screen.blit(pipe_surface,pipe)


#main game loop, renders every frame of the game
while True:
    #Event Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        #checks for keypresses
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #checks if space is pressed
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bird_movement = 0
                bird_movement -= 12
        if event.type == SPAWNPIPE:
            pipe_list.append(create_pipe())
            
    screen.blit(pipe_surface,(0,0))        
            
    #pipes
    pipe_list = move_pipes(pipe_list)
    draw_pipes(pipe_list)

              

    #rendering the background
    screen.blit(bg_surface,(0,0))

    #rendering the bird and a rectangle around that detects colisions
    screen.blit(bird_surface,bird_rect)
    
    #gravity
    bird_movement += gravity
    bird_rect.centery += bird_movement


    #more floor animation
    floor_x_pos -= 1
    draw_floor()  
    if floor_x_pos <= -576:
        floor_x_pos = 0    


    #Causes display update and defines framerate
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 2):

The background covers the pipes. You need to draw the pipes **after** drawing the background:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    #pipes
    pipe_list = move_pipes(pipe_list)
    # draw_pipes(pipe_list)              <--- REMOVE

    #rendering the background
    screen.blit(bg_surface,(0,0))

    # draw pipes
    draw_pipes(pipe_list)              # <--- ADD

    # [...]
```